# Move segue lines in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder

Is it possible to move the lines (representing a segue) connecting the view controllers to make my storyboard more aesthetically pleasing?

I tried a bunch of weird click combinations (or anything that to me would be an obvious way to move the line), to no avail. Any tricks I missed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To my knowledge, the segues are positioned automatically and cannot be moved.

To get aesthetically pleasing storyboards you can only reposition the view controllers which will also change the position of the segues.

If you need the aesthetics because you want to communicate the app structure to third parties, maybe you want to look at different and more suitable tools instead.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently just moving the view controllers around to the point I like it. Guess it's a slight obsession I have from using all those UML tools. We re-create the app structure in third-party tools for other parties, but this was just for internal use, as it could get somewhat cluttered sometimes.

Comment: I'm so glad that I don't have to manually move the lines around. :)

Comment: @JackieXu Well, then I guess it is time to head over to that checkmark button above...